# Easiest way to update Angular 4 page after login

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple Angular 4 project like this:

**app.component.html**

```
<alert></alert> <-- Alert service
<cat-header></cat-header> <-- Site header with Sign in button
<router-outlet></router-outlet> <-- Main content
<cat-footer></cat-footer> <-- Site footer
```

After Sign in button is pressed it goes to Login component (different page). It uses Authorization Service to check user in the database and if founded, store him in

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
```

After successful Sign In Login Component navigates to main page with

```
this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
```

Problem is that after navigation done there is no Header Component update (neither Constructor nor ngOnInit code is called). When I press Ctrl+F5 in my browser after initial navigation, the Header Component is updated like it should.

I have tried to search this case over the Internet and have founded some complex solutions like using Emitters or Dummy paths with page reload. But it looks very complex to solve such a simple task.

Here is my Header Component:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

currentUser: User;
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UserService) {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(data => {
        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
}
}
```

And here is code in Header Component template with Sign In button:

```
<a *ngIf="currentUser; else notLogedIn" href="javascript: void(0);" [routerLink]="['/login']">Log off</a>

<ng-template #notLogedIn><a href="javascript: void(0);" [routerLink]="['/login']">Log in</a>
```

So at this moment it just shows different link text.

Visualization of this logic:

1. [Main page after successful Login, User is logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h67LO.png)
2. [Main page after manual update with Ctrl + F5 or after click on the Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzk5q.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried different approaches and have made easiest solution from my point of view.

I have created a Service to check Current User state:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';   

@Injectable()
export class CurrentUserService {
itemValue = new Subject<string>();

set currentUser(user) {
  this.itemValue.next(user);
  localStorage.setItem('currentUser', user);
}

get currentUser() {
  return localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
}
}
```

and Subscribed on this Service from my Header Component:

```
currentUser: User;
constructor(private currentUserService: CurrentUserService) {
     currentUserService.itemValue.subscribe(currentUser => {
     this.currentUser = JSON.parse(currentUser);
    });
}
```

It works like a charm!

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a service to know if the user is loggedIn or not

```
<cat-header *ngIf="userService.isLoggedIn()"></cat-header>


isLoggedIn(){
   return true/ false ;
}
```

Comment: I have such check but inside my Header Component template. I have added this part of HTML code in my initial post.

Comment: so what exactly you are facing please  tell me I will help you

Comment: Problem is that **this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);** don't update the Header Component after navigating to the main page. I think that it is because <cat-header></cat-header> template is outside <router-outlet></router-outlet>, but don't know how to correctly trigger Header Component reload/update.

Comment: so you are having the main layout and modal-dialog under the same parent. So you cannot control this. pushing it one level down or using shared service will help you in this case

Comment: My Login Component is a different page with /login path. After successful login it navigates back to main page / path.

Comment: how you are knowing that login is success or failure? update a shared service variable use it in the main component and show/hide the navbar

Comment: I'm checking login state with localStorage.getItem('currentUser') variable. It is set with Authorization Service. But I need my navbar either user logged in or not, so I'm checking login state inside Header Component and showing correct button with *ngIf.

Answer (score 0):

**Another way**
I know it is an old question if you don't want to parse, another way can be:

*In Authentication.ts*

```
export class AuthService {
private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
public currentUser: Observable<User>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) 
{
   this.currentUserSubject = null;
   this.currentUser = null;
   const currentUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
   if (currentUser !== 'undefined') {
     this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(currentUser));
     this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
 }
}
```

And you can call it on component constructor like the following:

```
    constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthService) 
    {
       this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(currentUser => {
       this.currentUser = currentUser;
       });
    }
```